# Are there any directories of the official icons used in macOS?

Tags: macos, font, icon

Things like the share sheet, the forwards and backwards glyphs, the magnifying glass, etc. are standard across macOS.

Is there any official repository of these glyphs? It would seem to be extremely useful.

Comment: A lot of these are in the Apple Symbols font, starting around glyph 3875, but I don't know if that is what you want, or how complete it is.

Comment: You may also simply search all files ending in ".png" inside the /System folder. If you're using the latest alpha of `Find Any File`, you can then even see the results as images, browsing through them quickly.

Comment: No need for any 3rd party software, Finder will show the results as images too, in Icons or Cover Flow mode.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the icons are in the System folder. Just enter the System Folder, hit Cmd+F, click +, select Kind in the first dropdown box and Image in the second. This should get most of the icons.

Others are in the Apple Symbols font, as Tom pointed out.

A few more can be found here: `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`.